# Weird space above div when using line-height and <h2> elements

Tags: html, css

I try to have to div on the top of the page with a `<h2>` element centered in it (horizontally and vertically).

HTML

```
<div id="header"><h2>The header</h2></div>
```

CSS

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #9C27B0;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The weird effect I get is that there is a space between the top of the div and the upper edge of the window.

If I only write text in (without h2 tags) in the div no such problem appears. But, I cannot find any source explaining why line-height and `<h>` tags produce weird outcomes.

Comment: probably it's caused by the default margin applied to `h2`

Comment: it is due to you are having margin for <h> tag to remove it include this css to remove <h> tag margin #header h2{  margin : 0px;}

Answer (score 0):

Headers all have default margin/padding. You can delete them by applying this code.

**CSS**

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```